# Hide Approved status for certain users in users list

Tags: php, javascript, wp-admin, users

In the list of all users in wp-admin, i would like to hide the “Approved” status for certain users. These users only need to see “Pending” status to accept them.
I didn’t find any plugin to make this, and I don’t know how to code it in PHP/JS.

If you can help and send me an idea

Thank you

Edit:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `approved`? I don't see that in my WP installs user section

Comment: I mean this, as you can seen in this screenshot https://ecoleesadd-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/mateo_faivre_esadd_fr/EUz2rj_ND3VHjhysNX8cR3gBFQc4S0zTeDPojTUdULPQPg?e=SEVT0j

Comment: You mean in WP Admins user screen? Keep in mind not everybody can see that URL, you should edit your question and include the image in it by uploading it to stack exchange rather than a 3rd party host. Especially as a lot of people do not read the comments

Comment: Yes I mean in wp-admin of course. Thanks

Comment: I had to download your image from sharepoint then upload it using the built in image feature that uses imgur. don't host screenshots on 3rd party services like sharepoint in your questions